# Wordpress site not showing latest post only

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress site is a coded one, and recently I have created a new block on the main page to handle all the latest posts that come from one of my categories. But the problem is the first or latest post returns a blank white space on the page. I have other blocks on my page that do this but this issue doesn’t happen to them, and I’ve only copied their code. I tried to change the post’s categories and it works for others. Only the newly created category block creates this issue. I have already checked the elements of the empty post and it doesn't return an href block unlike the next post to it.

```
<div style="border: 2px solid #23429a; width: 210px; float: left; border-top-left-radius:3px; border-top-right-radius:3px;" >
       <!--TITLE-->
       <div style="background-color: #23429a; color: white; padding: 6.3px 6px; font-size: 16px;">
         <b>My category</b>
       </div>
       <!--CONTENT-->
       <div style="height: 190px; margin-top: -8px; margin-bottom: -8px;">
             <div class="test" style="margin: 10px 5px">
                <?php $the_thirdquery = new WP_Query(array('cat' => 32, 'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>
                <table style="font-size: 14px; margin: auto;">
                  <tbody>
                <?php while ($the_thirdquery -> have_posts()) : $the_thirdquery -> the_post(); ?>
                    <tr style="height: 35px;">
                      <td width="30px">
                         <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><?php the_time('m/d'); ?></font>
                         </font>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                        <div style="font-size: 13px; width: 140px;">
                        <?php if ($custom_post_type == "Clinic") { ?>
                          <a href= "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                     <!-- <td style="text-align: right; padding-left:25px;" width="20px">
                      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"> -->
                          <?php $custom_post_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', true);?>
                          <!-- <?php #echo $custom_post_type;?> -->
                        <!-- </font>
                      </font>
                    </td> -->
                    </tr>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry for my code.

But is there anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: You appear to be assigning a value to `$custom_post_type` for the first time here several lines _after_ `<?php if ($custom_post_type == "Clinic")` …?

Comment: @CBroe its an additional filter i made from whichever department posted it.

Comment: Doesn’t change the fact that this variable does not have to appear any value set yet (unless there’s more code above you didn’t show us) at the time you are first trying to check whether it equals `Clinic`.

Comment: Can you cut out exactly which line of code out of all these lines that you're experiencing trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing problems with `$the_thirdquery` a few lines in then I would presume that you haven't got sufficient args in the array to accomplish what you want to achieve from the `WP_Query`. Also, I'm not sure where the `$custom_post_type` call is coming from or being used as its being declared after the `if()` block. If it's a custom post type add it into the `$args`. Try this, see how it goes and comment your results back.

```
$args = array(
  'cat' => 32,
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'post_type' => 'clinic',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post(); {
  // add your code here for the query.
}
```

Comment: Yep, it is an custom post type but still it yields same results, the latest showing a blank space.